# TensorFlow 2.8.0 installing error using pip and poetry with python 3.10.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-poetry

**Edit 2**: Solved

I tried to install TensorFlow many times in different ways:

- Tried installing it in Windows(10 and 11), WSL2.0 , and Ubuntu OS.
- Tried installing it on 4 different computers, one of them has i7-11800H, RTX3060, and 16GB RAM.
- Tried installing it using pip and poetry.
- Tried installing it using CML (Powershell and Ubuntu) and PyCharm package manager.
- Tried venv and poetry shell for the environment.

The following result appeared every time (for example, after entering `poetry add tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow`)

```
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.10,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0
    - tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0

  Because no versions of tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem match >0.23.1,<0.24.0 || >0.24.0,<0.25.0 || >0.25.0
   and tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.23.1) requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem is forbidden.
  And because tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.24.0) requires Python >=3.7, <3.11
   and tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.25.0) requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem is forbidden.
  Because no versions of tensorflow match >2.8.0,<3.0.0
   and tensorflow (2.8.0) depends on tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (>=0.23.1), tensorflow (>=2.8.0,<3.0.0) requires tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (>=0.23.1).
  Thus, tensorflow is forbidden.
  So, because pythonproject4 depends on tensorflow (^2.8.0), version solving failed.

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\poetry\puzzle\solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties

    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.10,<3.11"
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.10,<3.11"
    For tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.10,<3.11"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

There is no problem with installing TF 2.8 on Python 3.9
But my question is: since I have Python 3.10.4 why the following error happens

`tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem requires Python >=3.7, <3.11, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.11,<4.0`

**Edit:**

When I manually edited the dependencies in .toml file to be like this:

> `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`
>
> `python = ">=3.10,<3.11"`

it installed most of the package then it failed in something and the following error appeared:

```
Using version ^2.8.0 for tensorflow

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file

Package operations: 34 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing certifi (2021.10.8)
  • Installing charset-normalizer (2.0.12)
  • Installing idna (3.3)
  • Installing pyasn1 (0.4.8)
  • Installing urllib3 (1.26.9)
  • Installing cachetools (5.0.0)
  • Installing oauthlib (3.2.0)
  • Installing pyasn1-modules (0.2.8)
  • Installing requests (2.27.1)
  • Installing rsa (4.8)
  • Installing google-auth (2.6.6)
  • Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
  • Installing google-auth-oauthlib (0.4.6)
  • Installing grpcio (1.46.0)
  • Installing markdown (3.3.7)
  • Installing tensorboard-data-server (0.6.1)
  • Installing tensorboard-plugin-wit (1.8.1)
  • Installing werkzeug (2.1.2)
  • Installing astunparse (1.6.3)
  • Installing flatbuffers (2.0)
  • Installing gast (0.5.3)
  • Installing google-pasta (0.2.0)
  • Installing h5py (3.6.0)
  • Installing keras (2.8.0)
  • Installing keras-preprocessing (1.1.2)
  • Installing libclang (14.0.1)
  • Installing opt-einsum (3.3.0)
  • Installing tensorboard (2.8.0)
  • Installing tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem (0.25.0)
  • Installing termcolor (1.1.0)
  • Installing tf-estimator-nightly (2.8.0.dev2021122109)
  • Installing typing-extensions (4.2.0)
  • Installing wrapt (1.14.1)
  • Installing tensorflow (2.8.0)

  EnvCommandError

  Command C:\Users\majda\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonproject3-pEOchWpC-py3.10\Scripts\pip.exe install --no-deps C:\Users\majda\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\9b\54\38\c69dfa96cba7e69e543db60e6f1bc9060f68c5cf51bdb1796760b5bfcc\tensorflow-2.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing c:\users\majda\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\artifacts\9b\54\38\c69dfa96cba7e69e543db60e6f1bc9060f68c5cf51bdb1796760b5bfcc\tensorflow-2.8.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
  Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\majda\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\pythonproject3-pEOchWpC-py3.10\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\external\\cudnn_frontend_archive\\_virtual_includes\\cudnn_frontend\\third_party\\cudnn_frontend\\include\\cudnn_frontend_EngineConfigGenerator.h'
  HINT: This error might have occurred since this system does not have Windows Long Path support enabled. You can find information on how to enable this at https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/enable-long-paths
  
  

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py:1195 in _run


Failed to add packages, reverting the pyproject.toml file to its original content.
```

**Edit 2 :**

If you use Ubuntu the second error won't happen. But if you use Windows the solution for that error according to [microfocus](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/filr/filr-4/filr-desktop/t47bx2ogpfz7.html) is:

1. Click Window key and type gpedit.msc, then press the Enter key. This launches the Local Group Policy Editor.
2. Navigate to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem.
3. Double click Enable NTFS long paths.
4. Select Enabled, then click OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using poetry, in your `pyproject.toml` edit manually:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.10,<3.11"
```